# cubic integral roots

Tags: algorithms, indefinite-integrals, turing-machines, cubics

I am trying to find the integral roots (if they exist) of the following polynomial. Additionally, it would be helpful if someone could explain an algorithmic approach to solving this.

$$ f(x) = 2x^3 - 12x^2 -14x + 120 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ 2x^3−12x^2−14^x+120\\ \\f(x)=2(x^3-6x^2-7x+60)=0\\check\\\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm5,\pm6,\pm10,\pm15,\pm20\pm30,\pm60$$ when check them,you will find  f(-3)=0 , f(4)=0 ,f(+5)=0 ,

so now divide by (x-4) and(x-4) ,and (x+3) to find simple form

I mean 2(x-5)(x-4)(x+3)